# why the key for apk is not generated

Tags: java, vue.js, cordova, quasar

I am trying to create an application on quasar (cordova)
https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/publishing-to-store
When forming a key "keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000"
I get an error
'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Тогда я захожу в C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin
I am trying to repeat this command at this address. But after filling out the form, enter the description of the image here
[image]
error - access denied

I cannot generate via build-generate signed bundle because I am missing this line in android studio enter image description here

Tell me, what am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore new-key.keystore -alias newkey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```